# How to get a value from an array key within an stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays

I'm building a php webapp and I want to get a list of id's from an array named $array.

```
stdClass Object
(
  [users] => Array
    (
      [0] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 90379747
          [id_str] => 90379747
        )
      [1] => stdClass Object
        (
          [id] => 30207605
          [id_str] => 30207605        
        )
    )
)
```

However when I try to get the value from the id key it somehow is not working.

```
echo "<h1>Result</h1>";

foreach ($array as $obj)
{
  echo $obj->id;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here. Other examples on stackoverflow seem to suggest this should work.

Comment: First, what you show is an object, not an array. So if `print_r($array)` indeed gives you what you show here then there is definitely no reason to expect that code to work. `$obj` will be an array inside that loop. `var_dump($obj)` to see that.

Comment: Can you add the class creation code to make this easier to anwer

Comment: Its part of twitteroauth

$array = $connection->get("followers/list", ["screen_name" => twitterdev, "count" => 10]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate an object, not an array. Try this way:

```
foreach ($array->users as $obj)
{
  echo $obj->id;
}
```

Comment: That works indeed, Thanks Bart